# Compute the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 2x}{x}=2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to compute the following limit, though I'm trying to cement the understanding of it using the definitions of limit, so would really appreciate your support in understanding this.

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 2x}{x}=2$

I know that $\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

and $\sin 2x = 2 \cos x \sin x$

Hence:

$|\frac{\sin 2 x}{x}-2|=\frac{|2\cos x \sin x-2x|}{|x|}=2\cdot \frac{\cos x \sin x}{x}-1$

This should then be $2-1 = 1$, which I can compute fine using logic, as $\frac{\sin x }{x} = 1; 2\cos(x) = 2;$ when $x = 0$

Although, I'm nervous in where I should take my understanding from above towards $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definitions to interpret the limit with clearness. Perhaps, an example and steps would help alleviate this anxiety. Although, whatever the help I'm really appreciative.

Comment: The words you are using to describe this problem are giving me anxiety

Answer (score 4):

You can just write$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{x}=2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}=2\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=2\times1=2.$$Or if you insist on using the double angle formula,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x}=2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=2\times1\times1=2.$$

Comment: This makes clearer sense, I shouldn't have replaced $-x$ for $\frac{p}{q}-1$. Although, how would yo approach it using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definitions, it's the conception of this and its application, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @no_'t'-lime I'm repeatedly using [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Limits_of_Functions/Real/Product_Rule) (the crux being [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Sequences/Real/Product_Rule)).